# Should the dupe message say "has a better answer" rather than "already has an answer"?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, languages

Precedent shows that some Question Foo can be marked as a duplicate of Question Bar, even though Foo was asked *before* Bar.<sup>(Cite: [267081](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267081))</sup> This shows that one question can be called a duplicate of another not based on time, but on quality of answer.<sup>(Cite: [251938](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938), [189782](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189782), [169388](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169388))</sup>

Thus, instead of:

> <sub>**This question already has an answer here:**</sub>
>   [Question Bar?](https://example.com) *N answers*

Shouldn't it read something like this?

> <sub>**This question has a better answer here:**</sub>
>   [Question Bar?](https://example.com) *N answers*

Or even more accurate to our methodology:

> <sub>**This question is posed and/or discussed better here:**</sub>
>   Question Bar? *N answers*

Comment: Please accompany any downvotes with a comment explaining why my question is not useful or shows no research. That way I can ask better questions in the future 

Answer (score 4):

No, it shouldn't.

While some older questions may be closed as duplicates of newer questions with higher quality answers, that doesn't always happen.  Sometimes questions are just closed as duplicates of older questions, without regard to answer quality.

In addition, I don't think the message should say "has a better answer" since "better" is subjective.  One user may find one answer to be more helpful, but another user may find the other answer to be more helpful.

Also, "has a better answer" implies that the duplicate question has been answered.  What if there's no answer on the duplicate question?  Then it wouldn't make sense to say "has a better answer".

Comment: This is why I added the 3rd case, which is one I think might fit the most scenarios.